# Select attributes from multiple tables with no association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, arel

If could really help me out with problem I have, I would really appreciate it. My problem is that I can not select attributes from certain tables that have no association between them.

To explain myself better, here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :measurement_blocks
 has_many :measurements, through: :measurement_blocks
end

class MeasurementBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :measurements
end

class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :measurement_block
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :measures
end

class Measure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
end
```

I can get a ProxyAssociation with

```
user.measurements
```

but what I really want is to include the device and measures names.

I have tried the following:

```
measurements = user.measurements

measurements.include("INNER JOIN ON devices (devices.id = measurements.device_id)")
```

but it does not work. Furthermore, as I mentioned before I want to 
include the measures and devices names along with the measurements. 
ActiveRecord is frustrating to me when there is no full association between models.

Thank you again.

[image]

Comment: Try to use `joins` instead of `include`

Comment: Thanx. I did. It only returns data from measurements. eg: #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Measurement id: 85, measure_value: 90.0, device_id: 26, measure_id: 28, created_at: "2015-04-15 13:01:08", updated_at: "2015-04-15 13:01:08", measurement_block_id: 79>, #<Measurement id: 86, measure_value: 80.0, device_id: 26, measure_id: 29, created_at: "2015-04-15 13:01:26", updated_at: "2015-04-15 13:01:26", measurement_block_id: 79>,

Comment: It will not show you associated data like this but when you will call the desired attrs, you will get the values